Prove $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{A'(x_k)}=0$, where $A(x)=\prod_{j=0}^n (x-x_j)$.
This is an identity related to Lagrange's interpolation formula found in Apostol's Calculus II.
Let $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$ be distinct real numbers, and
$$ A(x)=\prod_{j=0}^n (x-x_j),\quad A_k(x)=\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq k}}^n (x-x_j),\quad L_k(x)=\frac{A_k(x)}{A_k(x_k)}.$$
I have proved
$$ A'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n A_k(x),\quad \sum_{k=0}^n L_k(x)=1, \quad \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{A_k'(x)}{A'(x_k)}=0,\quad A'(x_k)=A_k(x_k). $$
Now I need to prove
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{A'(x_k)}=0. $$
The hint says picking a suitable value of $x$ and use the identities I have proved. In the third identity, if I could pick some $x$ so that $A_k'(x)$ equals some constant for every $k=0,1,2,\dots,n$, the identity would be proved, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any hint?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1337271/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436011/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104262/42969 – all found with Approach0

@MartinR   Thank you! I tried to search the formula directly in Mathematics StackExchange but with no avail. Thanks for letting me know the existence of Approacho.
